# replace -3.402823466e+38 with NaN or get rid of this value in a dataframe

Tags: python, no-data

I'm working with sentinel 2 images that cut with a bbox with QGis. Some of those images aren't completely under the bbox so Qgis put the lowest float value close to 0 as a NoData value.
I tried to indicate that i want a specific value as a NoData but it doesn't work with every pixel since I have now the specific value I told him to put -4.444444 but -3.402823466e+38 values aswell.

So I tried to remove it from the dataframe I'm working on (image opened with rasterio), with :

```
 df_annee.replace(-3.402823466e+38, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

I tried to put the value of the dataframe in a variable that I'm calling to replace it :

```
i = df_mois.loc[:,'Valeurs'][0][5]
df_annee.replace(i, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

I tried to replace it directly from the array with the script i'm using to create my dataframe :

```
src = (rasterio.open(each_directory))
array = src.read(1)
array[(array<-2)] = np.nan
array[(array > -2.412823466e+38 ) | (array < -1.401823466e+38 )] = np.nan
array[(array == -3.402823466e+38)] = np.nan
```

Nothing worked. The problem with this value is that I want to average the values of my images to plot it but seaborn plots consider -3.402823466e+38 as -3, my plot end up false and np.mean() or mean(df) doesn't recognize these values as NoData so my average ends up to be really close to 0 even when it's not.

This loop can find all my values but not the -3.402823466e+38 one :

```
for i in range(len(df_mois.loc[:,"Valeurs"])):
    for y in range(len(df_mois.loc[:,"Valeurs"][0])):
        for x in range(y): 
            #print(df_mois.loc[:,"Valeurs"][i][y][x])
            if df_mois.loc[:,"Valeurs"][i][y][x] < 0.001 and df_mois.loc[:,"Valeurs"][i][y][x] > -0.00001:
                print(df_mois.loc[:,"Valeurs"][i][y][x])
                print('coucou')
```

Another weird thing is that, my numbers are in float 32 but I have +38 numbers in my dataframe ...

What can I do ?

Comment: Since you're working with Sentinel-2 data, are you using netcdf files? Because if so those have built-in way of dealing with this.

Comment: No I'm working with tiff I didn't knew about netcdf though thanks !

Comment: This is a very strange behavior, which I cannot replicate using numpy arrays, so not sure how to help. As for the last statement, it is actually possible:
`>>> np.finfo(np.float32)`
`finfo(resolution=1e-06, min=-3.4028235e+38, max=3.4028235e+38, dtype=float32)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this specific value appears is unclear to me.
On the other hand, I was able to resolve my problem by looking at when it first started to appears in my images. I didn't noticed it at first because I did several treatments on QGis and it was able to handle it.

At first I,

1 - superimposed in Python with **otbcli_superimpose**
*only my bands at a resolution of 20 with a band at 10 to save time and didn't realised all my images weren't at the same spatial resolution (because I was in degre-EPSG 4326-)*

2- averaged my images with **BandMath in QGIS**
*The second problem was the NoData values. As for the spatial resolution, Bandmath in QGis was able to handle it (or hide it) but not python.There was a problem but QGis just went for it without telling me there was a problem, so I was able to average my images with Bandmath without noticing anything.*

3- wanted to plot those images with **Pandas, seaborn**
that's when I noticed my matrices were weird and that I wasn't able to handle the -3.402823466e+38 value.

So I did all the process again with :

1- **otbcli_superimpose** *all my images with one image*
2- **gdalwarp -cutline** *to cut all my images the same way, specifying the nodata value with **-dstnodata***
3- **gdalmerge.py** *to merge the images that where not in the same tile*
4- **otbcli_BandMath** *to average them.*

I think in the future I'll not use QGis again if I need to open my images with python afterwards I have no idea how to specify some parameters and QGis can run with it being implicit so that's not a good practice.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).